# Python - __init__ submodule using parent package

Tags: python

I have a package structure as:

```
parent_package/
    __init__.py
    module/
        __init__.py
```

In the parent `__init__.py` I have:

```
from __future__ import division

print(3/2) # 1.5
```

However, when I tried to reuse the import in its child, division does not take effect. In module's `__init__.py`:

```
from parent_package.__init__ import division

print(3/2) # 1!
```

Comment: Is division your own module or file? Couldn't you just import `division` in the module `__init__` ?

Comment: I think for good style, you should just use `from __future__ import division` everywhere. It's even shorter!

Comment: Your current import doesn't even make it clear that `division` is a future import: it could be a random function, variable or class defined in the parent. That is very confusing.

Comment: @9769953 I wanted modules to init following the root. Wished root \_\_init\_\_.py do the heavy lift (setup global config etc.) and modules somehow 'inherit' from it. I don't know if there's a better way to do it.

Comment: "I don't know if there's a better way to do it. ": see my first comment.

Comment: @9769953 there can be more imports other than `future`, and you need to copy & paste lines of imports everywhere. It is bad that you can't set global imports for a package in a shot.

Comment: Of course you can do things like `from .. import *`; it just won't work for future imports. (And you should define `__all__` in the main package then, or elsewhere. Also beware of circular imports if you start doing that.)

Comment: But you probably mean that it's unfortunate that there is not a package-wide setting for future directives (and only those), as that would near-instantly make a package Python 2/3 compatible. I can agree with that sentiment, and I guess it's part of how modules have grown into packages over time; bit of a historical artefact perhaps, even if `from future` is not that old.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misunderstanding how the `__future__` module works. `__future__` is a special module that is built into the python interpreter and changes how the interpreter parses and/or executes your code. In order for a `__future__` import to have the desired effect, it *must* be of the form

```
from __future__ import <feature>
```

(See [PEP 236](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0236/#syntax) for the exact specification.)

However, in addition to the `__future__` module that's built into the interpreter, `__future__` is *also* [a real module in the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__future__.html)! The import `from __future__ import divison` actually does two things: It enables the new division behavior, **and** it imports the feature specification from the real `__future__` module. This is what you'll see if you take a look at the value of `division` after the import:

```
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> division
_Feature((2, 2, 0, 'alpha', 2), (3, 0, 0, 'alpha', 0), 8192)
```

When you do `from parent_package.__init__ import division`, you're simply importing this variable. But you're not enabling the new division behavior.